# SQL timestamp, eliminate duplicate rows

Tags: sql, teradata

I've created a SQL query in teradata which at product price changes, but want to show the most updated - using the timestamp.  The issue however is that the data does have instances where the product_number, price, timestamp is repeated exactly, giving multiples values.  I'm looking to eliminate those duplicates.

```
 select a.product_number, a.maxtimestamp, b.product_price
 from    ( SELECT DISTINCT product_number ,MAX(update_timestamp) as maxtimestamp
 FROM product_price
 group by product_number) a
 inner join product_price b on a.product_number = b.product_number 
and a.maxtimestamp =   b.update_timestamp;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use a ROW_NUMBER + QUALIFY

```
select *
from product_price
qualify
   row_number() 
   over (partition by product_number
         order by update_timestamp desc) = 1;
```

Comment: Don't you need to also say "=1" or is that implied?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to simply move your `DISTINCT` operator to the outside query, or do a GROUP BY that covers all columns (doing it on just `maxtimestamp` will result in an error).

```
 select DISTINCT a.product_number, a.maxtimestamp, b.product_price
 from    ( SELECT product_number ,MAX(update_timestamp) as maxtimestamp
 FROM product_price
 group by product_number) a
 inner join product_price b on a.product_number = b.product_number 
 and a.maxtimestamp =   b.update_timestamp
```

or

```
 select a.product_number, a.maxtimestamp, b.product_price
 from    ( SELECT DISTINCT product_number ,MAX(update_timestamp) as maxtimestamp
 FROM product_price
 group by product_number) a
 inner join product_price b on a.product_number = b.product_number 
 and a.maxtimestamp =   b.update_timestamp
 GROUP BY a.product_number, a.maxtimestamp, b.product_price
```

As an aside, the DISTINCT in the inner subquery is redundant since you already have a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  select a.product_number, a.maxtimestamp, b.product_price
  from    ( SELECT DISTINCT product_number ,MAX(update_timestamp) as maxtimestamp
  FROM product_price
  group by product_number) a
  inner join product_price b on a.product_number = b.product_number 
  and a.maxtimestamp =   b.update_timestamp
  group by maxtimestamp ;
```